# how do you create buttons dynamically in c# windows phone one per file name?

Tags: c#, button, foreach, windows-phone

I have my app make a folder on the sdcard called "RpgApp"
when ever it creates a character it saves that character as a html file in that folder (all of this works, i have sdcard access in the manifest and i have .html added to the file associations) .This is important information as with out the sdcard access or the file association i would get a unauthorized access exception.

I now want to create a button per file in a stack panel, here is the code im using

```
private async Task readFiles()
    {
        z.test.Clear();
        StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
        StorageFolder folder = (await externalDevices.GetFolderAsync("RpgApp"));
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
        {
            z.test.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }


    public async void buttonTest()
    {
        await readFiles();
        foreach (string name in z.test)
        {
            Button button1 = new Button();
            button1.Height = 75;
            button1.Content = name;
            button1.Name = name;
            testStackPanal.Children.Add(button1);
        }
    }
```

there is no errors as far as the ide is concerned. but when i try to run buttonTest() i get two Systen.UnauthorizedAccessExceptions this is the error i got before when creating the files (fixed by adding .html to file associations)
there is no other files in the RpgApp folder, just forename-surname.html

i have been working at this most of the day and im stuck any ideas creatly appreciated

windows phone universal app (windows phone 8.1 and above)

EDIT
commenting out await readFiles(); and adding strings to z.test does then work fully so it is linked to the reading of the files, but we know the app has access to the folder and the html files as it can create the folder and the files.

EDIT2
throw checking each line, it is this line thats causing the error

```
StorageFolder folder = (await externalDevices.GetFolderAsync("RpgApp"));
```

in the readFiles method, and yet that is the folder name exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your methods you are calling asynchronous tasks that execute on a background thread. The exception `Systen.UnauthorizedAccessExceptions` exception is being thrown when you are trying to access objects created on the UI Thread from a background thread.

I would modify your code so that after you have finished reading the files that all subsequent actions are completed on the UI Thread. Such as (note not tested).

```
public async void buttonTest()
{
    await readFiles();
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        foreach (string name in z.test)
        {
            Button button1 = new Button();
            button1.Height = 75;
            button1.Content = name;
            button1.Name = name;
            testStackPanal.Children.Add(button1);
        }
    });
}
```

The method `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() { ... });` is designed to execute a method to manipulate the UI. The UI can only be manipulated from the UI Thread.

The code above was for Windows Phone 8 however 8.1 has replaced a few methods and to access the Dispatcher from WP8 you would use.

```
public async void buttonTest()
{
    await readFiles();
    CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        foreach (string name in z.test)
        {
            Button button1 = new Button();
            button1.Height = 75;
            button1.Content = name;
            button1.Name = name;
            testStackPanal.Children.Add(button1);
        }
    });
}
```

### Edit

Ok.. So I have created my own test enviroment to figure this out and I was not on the right track. Turns out the problem was reading the SD card files correctly. This is done on the simulator with these steps.

1) Open the package manifest and got to the `Declarations` tab. From here i created a new FileType Association (as pictured below)
[image]

2) Goto the`Capabilities` tab and ensure you have `Removable Storage` selected (so we can read the storage).

Now the next part only worked when I changed the way we read the files from the device. Instead of trying to load one folder we iterate through all the folders, I got the same Access Denied error when trying to query a specific folder (not sure why). I modified the code for the read files to iterate through all the folders and files adding the ones as required.

```
async Task readAllFiles(StorageFolder folder)
{
    var files =await folder.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        test.Add(file.Name);
    }

    var folders = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
    foreach (var child in folders)
        await readAllFiles(child);
}


public async void buttonTest()
{
    test.Clear();
    StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
    var folders = await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
    foreach (var folder in folders)
    {
        await readAllFiles(folder);
    }
    CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        foreach (string name in test)
        {
            Button button1 = new Button();
            button1.Height = 75;
            button1.Content = name;
            button1.Name = name;

            testStackPanal.Children.Add(button1);
        }
    });
}
```

You will notice that the `readAllFiles` method is recursive calling itself from a parent folder. Also I just created a simple `List<string> test` for the file names. This seemed to work.

Now if you really wanted to just read the RpgApp folder you could modify the code as following.. Notice now I return false if the Folder is Null or the folder name is RpgApp. We could change this even more if you are certain that the RpgApp folder will always be in the root directory of the removable storage.

```
async Task<bool> continueToReadAllFiles(StorageFolder folder)
{
    if (folder == null)
        return false;
    if (folder.Name.Equals("RpgApp", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            test.Add(file.Name);
        }
        return false;
    }
    var folders = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
    foreach (var child in folders)
        if (!await continueToReadAllFiles(child))
            return false;

    return true;
}


public async void buttonTest()
{
    test.Clear();
    StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
    var folders = await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
    foreach (var folder in folders)
    {
        if (!await continueToReadAllFiles(folder))
            break;
    }
    //.... commented out
}
```

Comment: Deployment is not a valid name space in windows phone 8 but a quick search showed to use CoreDispatcher instead

however with http://pastebin.com/ssKGqBKT
im getting the same error

Comment: My apologies I missed the Windows 8.1 at the very bottom. I have edited the answer. If this still doest work can you point me to the exact line you are getting the exception on? I assume its on the `testStackPanal...` line.

Comment: switched it to the CoreDispatcher when i got the error about dispatcher, double checked and my code does appear the same as the edit but as i say the same error pops up
sadly it does not tell me on what line the error is, i just see in the console 

A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

(yep twice) no errors as far as the IDE is concerned

Comment: found the line responsible and edited the main post, no idea how to fix though

Comment: your an absolute star!

the edit worked perfectly, i wonder why it wouldnt let me specify to scan just the RpgApp folder....that will bug me as everything i have read says it should of worked

the RpgApp will indeed always be located on the root of the sdcard, its created if not there before we get to this part of the code (impossible to reach this part of the code with out being created, hence the absence of a try block (though i perhaps should add one! )

again thank you this has been confusing me for hours

Comment: Glad it is sorted out, there is room for improvement on this method but should give you a starting point. Cheers. Nico